# Как через объединения нескольких таблиц cделать INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql

Доброе время суток!

Столкнулся с проблемой, не знаю, как решить, делая книжный каталог, я делал в БД столбцы жанры и авторы отдельно, объединяя их одним вызовом:

```
SELECT books.title, books.min_img, books.description, books.content,books.name_book, books.id_book, authors.author, genre.genre
    FROM authors, genre, books_to_author, books, books_to_genre
    WHERE genre.id_genre = books_to_genre.id_genre
    AND authors.id_author = books_to_author.id_author
    AND books_to_genre.id_book = books.id_book
    AND books_to_author.id_book = books.id_book
    AND genre.id_genre = '$id_genre '
```

Но теперь, делая админку, мне нужно заносить в БД данные и не знаю, как мне правильно сделать `INSERT INTO`, как связать их правильно, чтобы во все столбцы была запись.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 5):

Судя по всему, Вам придется использовать несколько insert. Если при создании таблиц вы использовали engine=innodb, то можете воспользоваться транзакциями для обеспечения сохранения всех данных и отката в случае ошибок. Например, можете написать так:

```
->   start transaction;
->     set autocommit=0;
->     insert into table1(col1, col2) values (v1, v2);
->     insert into table2(id, col3, col4) values (last_insert_id(), v3, v4);
->   commit;
```

Синтаксис можете посмотреть в [MySQL мануале](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)...

Лично я для всех операций с базой данных использую хранимые процедуры. В таком случае, имея процедуру

```
-> create procedure AddBook(author varchar(128), bookname varchar(128), ....)
-> begin
->   start transaction;
->     .....
->   commit;
-> end//
```

можно добавить книгу единственным вызовом

```
call AddBook('Steve McConnell', 'Code Complete', ...);
```

кроме этого, я бы переписал Ваш вызов SELECT используя INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT books.title, books.min_img, books.description, books.content,books.name_book, books.id_book, authors.author, genre.genre 
FROM books as b 
inner join books_to_author as b2a on b2a.id_book=b.id_book
inner join authors as a on a.id_author=b2a.id_author 
inner join books_to_genre as b2g on b2g.id_book=b.id_book 
inner join genre as g on g.id_genre=b2g.id_genre
where g.id_genre='$id_genre';
```

Comment: а чем отличается  INNER JOIN ? от WHERE он лучше?
да я чувствую мне нужно прочесть книгу по SQL честно я таких процедур не знаю

Comment: По поводу INNER JOIN - такая формулировка объединяет таблицы согласно условию указанному в выражении после ON, что логично в данном случае, так как у Вас книги, авторы и жанры однозначно связаны, а поиск Вы ведете по genre.id_genre - вот его то и оставим в where. Чтобы проверить эффективность запроса можете попробовать выполнить EXPLAIN SELECT books.title, ..... посмотреть на колонку rows - чем меньше общая сумма, тем меньше работы выполнять MySQL серверу. По поводу MySQL, если дружите с английским, для начала почитайте Build Your Own Database Driven Website Using PHP & MySQL (только основы)

Comment: Помимо вышесказанного, при использовании INNER JOIN Вы можете указать какие индексы использовать для объединения таблиц, а какие - нет, что позволит оптимизировать запрос. См. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html и http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Хранимые процедуры не должны делать commit или start transaction. Транзакции это несколько более высокоуровневая вещь. Лучше commit делать в вызывающей сессии а не внутри хранимки

Comment: INNER JOIN ничем не лучше. как по мне так синтаксис с where гораздо очевиднее и даже больше распространён. ничем другим кроме синтаксиса эти конструкции не отличаются.

Comment: большое спасибо! за помощь

Comment: 2 AndrewFrolov - С чего Вы взяли что

> Хранимые процедуры не должны делать commit или start transaction. Транзакции это несколько более высокоуровневая вещь. Лучше commit делать в вызывающей сессии а не внутри хранимки

1. Где ссылка на соответствующий раздел мануала? Вот вам пожалуйста http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html мануал - почитайте на досуге, разберитесь. 2. Что значит "несколько более высокоуровневая вещь"? Это вообще "разные вещи". И ничто не мешает вызывать "одно из другого", между прочим.

Comment: 3. Что значит "лучше делать коммит из вызывающей сессии"? commit нужно делать на том же уровне где Вы делаете start transaction. И,вообще говоря,хранимая процедура выполняется в контексте "вызывающей сессии", если Вы так уж хотите "commit делать в вызывающей сессии"
4. Действительно, для INNER JOIN иных отличий кроме синтаксиса вроде бы нет, однако для LEFT JOIN (если понадобится) рони есть. Обычно (по меньшей мере в официальной документации MySQL) для выборки из нескольких таблиц используют JOIN. И мне кажется **логичнее** отделить **условие поиска** (WHERE) от **отношений между таблицами**.

Comment: 1 при чём тут мануал? я говорил о правильном подходе к кодингу. хранимки не должны начинать или завершать транзакции, потому что вызывающий код может заходеть вызвать несколько хранимок в одной транзакции. вообще commit во всём приложении должен быть только один :) меньше багла будет.